# Quick sort using median as pivot working (but shows incorrect count for comaprisons)

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort, median

I am using Quick sort in python to sort a list of numbers.This has to be done using the median as the pivot.
How am i finding the median ?
It is the second largest no.(out of a list of 3 numbers which are first,middle and last element of the original list)

If the list is of length even(2j),the middle no will be the jth element.

If the list is of length odd(say 5),the middle no. will be the 3rd element

My code works successfully.However, the total no. of comparisons made are incorrect(found using the variable **tot_comparisons**)

What am i doing?

1.Finding the pivot (which is the median of first,middle and last element)

2. Replacing the pivot found above with the first element(because i already have the code ready for quicksort,with the first element as pivot)

I do not need the code.I have my posted below which is working successfully(except for the total no. of comparisons part). I only need to know the mistake in my code

```
def swap(A,i,k):
    temp=A[i]
    print "temp is "
    print temp
    A[i]=A[k]
    A[k]=temp


def find_median(input_list,start,end):
    #print 'input list is'
    #print input_list

    temp_list1=[]
    temp_list1.append(input_list[start])    
    if len(input_list) % 2 ==0:
        middle_element_index=(len(input_list) / 2)-1
        middle_element=input_list[middle_element_index]
        temp_list1.append(middle_element)
    else:
        middle_element_index=len(input_list)/2
        middle_element=input_list[middle_element_index]
        temp_list1.append(middle_element)    
    temp_list1.append(input_list[end])
    temp_list1.sort()
    #print temp_list1
    if len(temp_list1)==3:
        print temp_list1[1]    
        return temp_list1[1]
    elif len(temp_list1)==2:
        print temp_list1[1]    
        return temp_list1[1]
    else:
        print temp_list1[0]    
        return temp_list1[0] 


def partition(A,start,end,median_index):

    swap(A,start,median_index)
    pivot=A[start]
    pivot_index=start + 1
    for i in range(start+1,end+1):
        if A[i] < pivot:
            swap(A,i,pivot_index)
            pivot_index+=1
    swap(A,pivot_index-1,start)
    return pivot_index-1

def quicksort(A,start,end):
    global tot_comparisons
    if start<end:
        median=find_median(A, start, end)
        median_index=A.index(median)

        pivot_index=partition(A,start,end,median_index)
        tot_comparisons+=end-start
        print "pivot_index"
        print pivot_index
        print "ENDS"


        quicksort(A, start,pivot_index-1)

        #tot_comparisons+=end-pivot_index
        #quicksort(A, pivot_index, end)

        quicksort(A, pivot_index+1, end)

#A=[45,21,23,4,65]

#A=[21,23,19,22,1,3,7,88,110]
#A=[1,22,3,4,66,7]

#A=[1, 3, 7, 19, 21, 22, 23, 88, 110]
#A=[7,2,1,6,8,5,3,4]

temp_list=[]
f=open('temp_list.txt','r')
for line in f:
    temp_list.append(int(line.strip()))
f.close()
print 'list is '
#print temp_list
print 'list ends'

tot_comparisons=0
#quicksort(A, 0, 7)
quicksort(temp_list, 0, 9999)
#quicksort(temp_list, 0, len(temp_list))
print 'hhh'
print temp_list
print tot_comparisons
#print A
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.   In this case, show the output you got, the output you expected, and perhaps explain why the latter is the correct output.

Comment: Please clarify your algorithm.  Does the pivot have to be the median element (the one in the middle of the *sorted* values) or the middle (whatever happens to be halfway through the *unsorted* list)?  Your text clearly indicates the median -- which requires at least a partial sort *before* choosing the pivot -- but your code implements the median of the first, middle, and last.

Comment: Why did you code such a tortured path to finding the middle index?  It's a simple expression.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've found the critical problem: **find_median** grabs the left and right elements of the given list, but then adds the middle element of the *original* list.  Thus, if you're looking to sort list positions 5:7, you grab elements 5, 7, and 3.  The last should be element 6.  This is likely to force your through extra sorting work.

The middle element has index

> (start+end) / 2

(integer division; it looks like you're using Python 2.? ).  You don't need separate cases for odd and even lengths.  The position depends on the given list, *not* the original length, **len(input_list)**.

Just make a list of the three needed elements, sort it, and return the middle element.  Since there's only one temp list, which is obviously a list, let's shorten that name.

```
temp = [
    input_list[start],
    input_list[end],
    input_list[(start+end) / 2]
]
temp.sort()
return temp[1]
```

You can reduce this to a one-command function.  I'll rename **input list** as simply **in** to help readability.

```
return sorted( [ in[start], in[end], in[(start+end) / 2] ] )[1]
```